# Weird IndexOf() behavior with substrings having escape characters

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

I'm trying to find all indexes of the string "\r\n" (basically line feed and return) in a large string.

I need to do this since i have to write the large string to a PDF file line by line (i have to call the newline API of the dll i'm using after writing the preceding line).

Here is the short version of the code:-

```
    string fileContents = "abc\r\n\r\ndef\r\nghi";

    int pos = -1; 

    int start = 0;

    while ((pos = fileContents.IndexOf("\r\n", start)) != -1)
    {
        //extract string
        //write string to PDF
        //call newline API

        start = pos + 1;

    }
```

The expected positions of "\r\n" in fileContents variable are 3,7 and 14. However, on debugging the code, the values in pos variable are 3, 5 and 10.

What seems to be wrong with my indexOf() call?

Comment: I think your assumptions are wrong, can you elaborate how you arrived at 3, 7 and 14?

Comment: `\r` and `\n` are counted as 1 not 2 as '\n' is a char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\n` or any other special char are special char.... which means even if you write them with 2 chars it's in fact just 1 char :

"abc\r\n\r\ndef\r\nghi"

```
 0 : a
 1 : b
 2 : c
 3 : \r
 4 : \n
 5 : \r
 6 : \n
 7 : d
 8 : e
 9 : f
 10: \r
 11: \n
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is supposed to be 3, 5 and 10.

The `\r` and `\n` etc. counts as **one** character, not two. Escape characters are one character in code, not two, even though they are written using two characters in the string.

You count like this:

```
a_b_c_\r_\n_\r_\n_d_e_f_\r_\n_g__h__i
0_1_2_3__4__5__6__7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the \n or \r characters will appear as single characters - not two. This means that the positions you're seeing are correct. Just count it out with each \x char counting as one char

Answer (score 1):

Below can be the better solution to your problem

```
    string s = "abc\r\n\r\ndef\r\nghi";
    List<String> lines = s.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray()).ToList();

    lines.RemoveAll(str => str == "");

    foreach (string l in lines)
        Response.Write(l + "<br/>");
```

Comment: Yes, it does seem snappy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to search for the literals the way you originally wanted, as an alternative for the rest of the answers.

First transform your string to escape all the literals:

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"));

provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(fileContents), writer, null);

string fileContents2 = writer.ToString();
```

And then search in this way:

```
.IndexOf("\\r\\n", start)
```

Comment: He will need to escape the source string too.

Comment: They're searching for the carriage return and newline characters, not the escape sequence representing them.